# Showdown custom headers html

Tags: javascript, html, markdown, showdown

[Showdown](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown) is markdown to HTML converter written in Javascript.

The problem is that all my headers are written in Russian language and Showdown do not add `id` attribue because it can work with Latin symbols only.

For example:

```
(new showdown.Converter()).makeHtml(' # Some header ')
<h1 id="someheader">Some header</h1>
```

Example with Russian symbols:

```
(new showdown.Converter()).makeHtml(' # Заголовок ')
<h1 id="">Заголовок</h1>
```

Is there a way to customize showdown output so I can cast handle Russian symbols in markdown headers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using the GitHub compatible IDs:

```js
var converter = new showdown.Converter();
converter.setOption('ghCompatibleHeaderId', true);
console.log( converter.makeHtml('# Заголовок ') );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/showdown/1.6.4/showdown.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great answer thank you! One more quetion. Is there a way to add a link inside <h> tag (link to anchor just like in books)? How can I do so?

Comment: Yes. It is commonly used on documentation sites! To make it handy to share link to header.

Comment: You should be able to `converter.makeHtml('# [Заголовок](#inpageid) ')`

Comment: Is there a way to add this link automatically (when converting from md to html)?

Comment: No, but you should ask that on a different question. I don't use showdown

Comment: Ok. Thank you again!